# Adverbs with prepositions

Tags: adverbs

Much to my surprise, I've read recently that some adverbs do not inherit prepositional constructions from the adjectives they come from, for example:

> "The proof of Theorem 3 is **similar to** that of Theorem 2"

is OK, but

> "Theorem 3 can be proved **similarly to** Theorem 2"

is not quite correct.

Is that indeed true?

This may be the reason why sometimes one can find "similar" in phrases playing the role of "sentence adverbs", like

> **Similar to** the situation in Section 2, we will now consider etc.

This default of English adverbs causes problems when translating e.g. from Slavonic languages, where adverbs like "similarly", "analogously" connect with prepositions.

Comment: What would you use with *similarly* if not *to*? The problem with the "Theorem 3..." sentence is what is being compared: it's the ***proving*** of Theorem 3 being compared to Theorem 2 ***itself***. Your "sentence adverb" should be *Similarly*. I'm not sure what the question is here, because it seems to be predicated on something which is not the case.

Comment: I'd like to see this question cleaned up a bit. I think the OP is saying that *is similar to* is OK but *proved similarly to* is not. But @AndrewLeach is correct. What *other* word would one use after *proved similarly*?

Comment: It's an interesting observation. The assumption normally is that derived lexical items inherit the affordances of their roots, like whether they can take a complement and what kind, government of prepositions (as here), presuppositions, etc. I agree that _similarly to_ has something wrong with it, but can't quite figure out what. @Andrew seems to have at least part of it, but while adverbs are not unexplored territory, they display an awful lot of variation, and there is considerable irregularity involved already in derivational morphology.

Comment: I wonder if there's an AmE/BrE difference here. I see nothing wrong at all with *similarly to*.

Comment: @Andrew: I speak AmE, and I also see nothing at all wrong with *theorem 3 can be proved similarly to theorem 2*.

Comment: Maybe some people are uneasy with the OP's sentence because they sense an ambiguity. You could interpret it as *"Theorem 2 can be proved. Theorem 3 can also be proved."* rather than *"Theorem 3 can be proved using similar techniques"*.

Comment: @PeterShor: In Russian, there's a way to deal with such ambiguity: a comma before "similarly", giving "Theorem 3 can be proved, similarly to Theorem 2". Such a sentence would equal "Theorem 2 can be proved. Theorem 3 can also be proved". Without a comma, there's no ambiguity (if the sentence is in Russian). Is comma allowable in  that position in English too, I wonder.

Comment: @CopperKettle: Just as in Russian, the comma before *"similarly"* works in English and singles out the same meaning. But without the comma, I feel there's still ambiguity in English. Maybe because *similarly* is usually used as a sentence adverb rather than whatever the alternative is called, some people are uncomfortable using it to modify a verb. [Is there a name for the alternative? I tried a cursory search on Google, and the best I could find was *"garden-variety adverb"*.]

Comment: @JohnLawler I have some extremely tentative theories as to why - 1) It garden paths you into a *proved similar to* reading. 2) Double 'l' there a bit off-putting in this position in sentence. 3) We avoid it to avoid problems with 'discourse marker *similarly*. But the one I'm tending towards is that *I did it similarly to how John did it* - it's a manner adverb and what is similar is not the theorem but the *way* it was proved. Therefore *similarly to how theorem 3 was* is marginally better. Any mileage in any of those?

Comment: @Araucaria: _similarly to how John did it_ does sound better. I think it must be the fact that this _to_ has an embedded wh-clause as an object, thus paralleling the clausal adverbial _similarly_ is modifying.

Comment: I agree with the observation. "He was angry about the insult.  He stomped angrily out of the room.  *He stomped angrily about the insult out of the room."  I see nothing natural about derived words inheriting "affordances".

Answer (score 1):

Some great answers here. It's been noted obliquely already, but "the devil is in the details," as they say. In English, as in many languages, word position does affect meaning or at least grammatical correctness. "Similarly" would need to either be offset with a comma or two, as in "Similarly, theorem 3 can be proven" or "Theorem 3, similarly, can be proven using the method used for Theorem 2." Putting the adverb in its "natural" position, though, it would read, "can be similarly proven", which is probably the simpler construction to explain if maintaining the same part of speech as the language you are translating from is the goal. I might propose two sentences for clarity and simplicity. "Theorem 2 provides a method that is useful for proving other theorems as well. Theorem 3 can be similarly proved."

Answer (score 0):

> "The proof of Theorem 3 is similar to that of Theorem 2"

You are saying here that the *proofs* are similar to each other.

The verb phrase "is similar" has "Theorem 3" as a subject.

> "Theorem 3 can be proved similarly to Theorem 2"

You are saying *the method in which the theorems were proved*  are similar to each other.

This is because "similarly" modifies "proved."

The second sentence would be more clear if it said:

> "Theorem 3 can be proved *in a similar manner* to Theorem 2"